# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token N in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

I have made a small vanilla javascript code to fetch api but it is throwing the error "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token N in JSON at position 0". I m not able to understand, exactly why the error is caught. Can somebody help me to resolve this.

```
const config = {
  url: "https://randomuser.me/",
  numberCards: 24
};

fetch(`${config.url}&amount=${config.numberCards}`)
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(apiResponse) {
    // Output API response to console to view.
    console.log(apiResponse);
  });
```

Comment: What is the response you get?

Comment: main.js:7 GET https://randomuser.me/%20&%20amount%20=24 404 (Not Found) and  Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token N in JSON at position 0

Comment: Well there you go `Not found` is not valid JSON, so it fails to parse. You need to check if the response actually succeeded first.

Comment: Status:
200 (OK)
Time:
42 ms

It is actually hitting the API and response is shown.....But whenever I try I get uncaught (in promise) error

Comment: In that case, that API is being stupid and returning a "success" with an error message in it. If the API is under your control, you should change it. If it isn't...I suppose you have to filter out error messages like that one before attempting to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of this.

```js
const config = {
  url: "https://randomuser.me/",
  numberCards: 24
};

fetch(`${config.url}&amount=${config.numberCards}`)
```

It should be,

```js
const config = {
  url: "https://randomuser.me/api/",
  numberCards: 24
};

fetch(`${config.url}?amount=${config.numberCards}`)
```

It's because the json data are from "https://randomuser.me/api/". Not "https://randomuser.me/". And the query strings must begin with a "?" mark. "&" mark is used to separate query strings. (like this "https://example.com/?amount=24&hi=en")